# Dependence of Klein-Gordon solution only on spatial coordinates

Tags: field-theory, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

I am studying QFT with the Peskin and Schroeder textbook, and I am new to this area of physics. I'm struggling with the solution of the Klein-Gordon equation using Fourier integral as a continuum set of oscillators:

\begin{equation}
\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_\mathbf{p}}} \left(a_\mathbf{p} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} + a^\dagger_\mathbf{p} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}\right).
\end{equation}

The question is: why doesn't the field $\phi$ depend on time? My answer is that this solution is applicable only in the Schrödinger picture, where the field is a function of spatial coordinates, not time.

The postscriptum question: Can we obtain this solution without knowledge of the harmonic oscillator? Specifically, I mean that perhaps it can be obtained without the procedure of canonical quantization, can't it?

I would appreciate any assistance: from simple reasoning to a purely formal derivation of formulas.

Answer (score 0):

It does. The bold x notation represents the spacetime 4-vector components, so depends on time and space. The solution is not at all due to second quantization: you’re putting the cart before the horse. That solution is just the solution of the classical Klein Gordon equation, in which we then do second quantization to make it an operator.

Comment: And if it helps, I’ve made a video here (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lFLrImjs4iQ&list=PLqeSalmyAzGHvxf_b2B1hVBWzk0FAUkE_&index=15&t=1628s&pp=iAQB) explaining how to get the solution

Comment: I've seen in «Notations and conventions» that bold letters are for spatial coordinates and ordinary letters are for $D = 3+1$ spacetime.

Comment: Well, then in that case what you have is the solution to the KG equation without considering time evolution. Similar to how you can have a wave function without considering time evolution. But still, the full solution does depend on t, though. You can check this by plugging e^{-ikt}e^{ikx} and you’ll see it solves the equation.